# ResponseNotReady exception in httplib2 error

Tags: python, httplib2

I'm just tryiing to execute a particular api to get the object lists ,

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http()
print ('=== G E T T I N G ===')
resp_headers, content = h.request("http://content.guardianapis.com/search?
q=obama&format=json", "GET")
print ('=== D O N E ===')
```

This is giving me this error while running from IDLE2.7:-

```
raise ResponseNotReady()
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Provide the *full* code. What is `h`? Where is it defined?

Comment: have you added: headers={'content-type':'application/json'} ?

Answer (score 0):

this is working fine

```
import httplib2

h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
(resp_headers, content) = h.request("http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=obama&format=json", "GET")

print content
```